# RHEL network service restart

Tags: networking, rhel

I modified the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file to set a static IP for my RHEL system. Then I tried to use the command `service network restart` to make the change stick.  However, it became stuck with the last message "Shutting down interface eth0". The network service has really been shut down since I can't connect via the old IP any more (nor the new one).

Why did it fail to restart the network with the new settings?

Also, since the network service on my RHEL system (accessed remotely) is down, how can I restart it? I need to be able to reconnect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you might have made an error in the new configuration. Usually, if the configuration is correct, and you change your IP, you'd be able to connect after the service restart (To the new IP).

If this is a remote server, your only option is to have someone that has physical access to the server help you out

Comment: Thanks. I did make an error in the new configuration,i.e., the static ip I assigned is in use with another machine. Is there a way of checking available ip's?

Comment: ping the ip before assigning it